# creating a text to speech application for any text highlighted

Tags: c#, python, .net, text-to-speech

I apologise for the broad question I am about to ask. However my brother has recently become partially sighted. I want to help him use his laptop again which runs windows 10.

I want to make an application to help him. What I want to create is something where he can highlight some text and right click and have an option "Text To Speach". I believe I know how to do this part after by editing the registry.

When he clicks this I want the text to be read aloud to him, ideally with a small floating menu with a pause, rewind & play button.

Any help to get me started would be very much appreciated. I have experience in c# mainly. Although happy using Python, Javascript. Open to all options.

I have been looking at various tts software but they seem a bit different to what I would like.

Comment: Look into the Windows 10 Accessibility Features. It already has, built in, many features that can help him out.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the major software OS (iOS, Android, Windows, etc.) have built in accessibility features. Check this link out specifically for Windows 10

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/accessibility/windows?activetab=pivot_1%3aprimaryr2